# avoid DOM manipulation using jQuery in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and working on a simple CRUD application. I understand that I must avoid DOM manipulation using jQuery if I can.

I am displaying data on the page after I get data from server using ng-repeat. 
My problem is that I want to remove the row from the DOM when I delete the row data from the server. I have accomplished this using jQuery for now.

I have this code:

View

```
<div>
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Add Project</a><br>

Project Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search.projectName" id="search.projectName" />
<br>
<br>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Project ID</td>
        <td>Project Name</td>
        <td>WBS</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:search" id="{{project.id}}">
        <td>{{project.id}}</td>
        <td>{{project.projectName}}</td>
        <td>{{project.WBS}}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteProject(project.id)" >Delete</a> 
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="editProject(project.id)" >Edit</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
enterprise.controller('projectController', ['$scope','$route','$modal','projectService',function($scope,$route,$modal,projectService) {
$scope.projects = projectService.getAllProjects();
$scope.deleteProject=function(projectID){
    projectService.deleteProject(projectID).$promise.then(function(){
        $('#' + projectID).remove();
    },function(){
        console.log('Delete failed');
    });
};}]);
```

I understand that I must not use **$('#' + projectID).remove();** and make use of directives for this kind of stuff. In case of non ng-repeat scenarios this could have been pretty easy. How should this be approached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simply actually, `splice` out the index you want gone by passing `$index` to your `delete` function:

```
ng-click="deleteProject(project.id, $index)"

$scope.deleteProject=function(projectID, index){
    projectService.deleteProject(projectID).$promise.then(function(){
        $scope.projects.splice(index, 1);
    },function(){
        console.log('Delete failed');
    });
};
```